# Calculate Tanimoto coefficient

Tags: mysql, r

I want to calculate Tanimoto Coefficient(Intersection of sets/Union) for the disease pairs.The sample data is below, just for 1 disease pair.
where disease 1 is NK cell defects and disease 2 is Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency.

Set 1 is Disease 1 (NK cell defects) which has all the genes from Gene1 column.

Set 2 is Disease 2 (Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency) which has all the genes from Gene2 column.

```
**Gene1** **Gene2**  **Disease1**   **Disease2**
IMPDH1  XDH NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PPP3R2  ADA NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PPP3R2  NPR1    NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PPP3R2  IMPDH1  NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PPP3R2  IMPDH2  NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PPP3R2  PPP3R2  NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PPP3R2  RRM1    NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
NPR1    POLA1   NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PPP3R2  ITGAL   NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
ITGAL   NPR1    NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
CASP3   NPR1    NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PTK2B   NPR1    NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
TNF GUCY1A2 NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
PTK2B   GUCY1A2 NK cell defects Adenylosuccinate lyase deficiency
```

Any suggestions, on how to do this in MySQL or R

Thanks,

Rohan

Comment: Can you define your intersection and union in this case? And reproducible data will go a long way in helping people answer. Try using `dput` on your data.frame.

Comment: Set 1 is Disease1 which includes all the genes in Gene1,Set 2 is Disease2  which includes all the genes in Gene2 column.Intersection is the number of common genes in Gene1 and Gene2 which are IMPDH1,PPP3R2,ITGAL,NPR1.   Union is the total number of Genes in Gene1 and Gene2 Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random input data-

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(
  G1=1:5,
  G2=3:7,
  D1="A",
  D2="B"
  )

DT[,
   list(
     intersectG = length(intersect(G1,G2)),
     unionG = length(union(G1,G2)),
     Tanimoto = length(union(G1,G2))/length(intersect(G1,G2))
     ),
   by = c('D1','D2')]
```

Output -

```
   D1 D2 intersectG unionG Tanimoto
1:  A  B          3      7 2.333333
```

Answer (score -1):

Learn to search:

```
 install.packages("sos")
 library("sos")
 findFn("Tanimoto")
```

getGeneSim {GOSim}  R Documentation

Compute functional similarity for genes

Description

Calculate the pairwise functional similarities for a list of genes using different strategies.
Usage

```
getGeneSim(genelist1, genelist2=NULL, similarity="funSimMax", similarityTerm="relevance", 
           normalization="Tanimoto", method="sqrt", avg=(similarity=="OA"), verbose=FALSE)
```

Comment: There seems to have been a "driveby downvote" on this 6 year old posting. The first part still seems relevant since `sos::findFn` still succeeds, although the GOSim package doesn't seem to be around anymore.